# DropzoneJs - Manually setting error message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js

I am using [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesreached)/[react-dropzone](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) and I noticed a bug in FF that if you drag a folder in the file type is blank.

In FF (file type is blank when you drag in a folder that contains images)
[image]

In Chrome
[image]

I believe because of this when I have in my code

```
  this.djsConfig = {
     acceptedFiles : 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
    };
```

that since the type: "" (when it should actually be image/jpeg) it gets rejected in Firefox.

I don't know if the creator will ever fix it, so I need to do a work around. So I figured that I can do this

```
handleFileAdded(file) {

    if(isFirefox){
      const extension = this.getExtension(file.name);
      if(!acceptedFiles.split(",").includes(extension)){


      }
    }
}
```

I just dont' know how to manually set the file in an error state with message "filetype is not accepted"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? "if you drag a folder in the file type is blank." What does this mean? Dragging a folder with a file without an extension inside? Can you provide a code sandbox? Or can we reproduce the problem with this example? http://reactdropzone.azurewebsites.net/example/

Comment: I added some screenshots, hopefully that is more clearer. No the example that is on the website does not seem to reject any file(ie you can drag a .exe in and it will allow it in)